# Relationship between two variables in two groups: a test of correlations coefficients or a WIlcoxon test using ratios?

Tags: inference, biostatistics, hypothesis-testing

I would love your opinion on this one. I'll make it quick.

- I have measures of the volume in two areas of the brain (let's call them X and Y). They are distributed non-normally (I am using nonparametric tests). I took these measurements from people with a condition and people without it. These two areas are subparts of a larger part of the brain.
- I want to see if, in people with the condition, X is smaller than Y, or vice versa. But I want to use people without the condition as controls, so I seem to have two choices:

1. Comparing the ratio of X and Y in condition vs control (with Wilcoxon test)
2. Comparing the correlations of X and Y in condition vs control (with Fisher r to z transformation)

To me, they seem almost the same, but I'm not sure if there are any assumptions I'm making here. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see that there's much to be gained by looking at correlations. Based on your knowledge of the subject matter, decide whether it's the difference or the ratio of the volumes that you care about.

If it's the difference, just model the differences `(Y - X)` with respect to condition/control, either parametrically or nonparametrically.*

If it's the ratio, it's often best to model that in a logarithmic scale, so you express the ratio `Y/X` as `log(Y) - log(X)` and model that difference in the log scale with respect to condition/control. My hunch is that this difference on the log scale will be close enough to normally distributed within each of the condition and control groups to allow a standard parametric test. If I'm wrong, you still can use the Wilcoxon test.

---

*If what you care about is the *difference or ratio* of the volumes of regions X and Y, then it doesn't really matter for parametric tests whether each of X and Y is normally distributed. What matters is whether their *difference or ratio* is close enough to normally distributed, within *each* of the condition and control groups.